# Sitecore :Insert Image from Media library Manger not auto filling Alt text

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Here are the Steps:

1. Edit Sitecore UI content Item
2. Scroll to Content section --> Click on Show Editor
3. Richtext Editor --> Image manager --> Select an Image
4. Missing Alt Text value from the Image selected.

Is there any way to get the Alt Text auto filled from the Image stored in MediaLibrary which has existing Alt value?

Comment: And what is the code you use to render that image?

Comment: @Marek Musielak I am not using any code to render the image. The issue is in Sitecore UI which is not picking the alt text value of the image  in html video of the richtext field.